# Grafana IFRAME panel autorefresh

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, grafana

I'm currently getting into grafana. I've been trying to embed a panel using an iframe in html.
Supposedly by adding ?refresh=5s to the link of a panel should make it refresh/update every five seconds. In practice however it seems that within an iframe this doesn't update.

`<iframe id="test" src="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/uniqueID/alarms?panelId=2&from=now-3h&refresh=5s" width="900" height="400"/>`

The panel/iframe above doesn't auto update. However if I were to click the link it, it then refers me to a page with only that given panel and it does auto refresh/update. Is there anyone who has faced this issue before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo it's been a while. But I've found the answer is found by changing from an iframe to an object.

When using it in an  html element the autorefresh does apply. The time thing mentioned in the answer above, didn't fix it for me personally.

As Esset mentioned some code examples might be handy.

What I initially started with (and DOES NOT work). This is if I remember correctly how grafana 'gives' it when you click share:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/hA2qsUiVz/[board-name]?orgId=1&refresh=5s&from=now&to=now-2h&panelId=5&theme=light" frameborder="0"/>
```

My findings however showed that this would not automatically update (whether I did or didn't add the refresh=5s to the url or not.

By changing this to an object as follows:

```
<object class="grafana-iframe"
            data="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/hA2qsUiVz/[board-name]?orgId=1&refresh=5s&from=now&to=now-2h&panelId=5&theme=light"></object>
```

It does make use of the theme=light edit and refreshes every 5 seconds as well. I must admit I'm not entirely sure why it behaves this way but these were my findings.

I have thus decided to use `<object>` to embed grafana panels on other pages.

Comment: Please show some code on what you did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Esset, my answer should now be clearer. If you have any questions left, do not hesitate to ask me :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue with the url parameters, I noticed this on **Grafana 8.5.2** earlier this week when developing, when you attempt to do an export in grafana it looks like this :

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/VCqhZiCnz/your-result-here?orgId=1&from=1654851072856&to=1654872672856&panelId=4" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

However if you look at the `from` and `to` parameters, the time range isn't set properly which means it won't be reacting to any new data coming through, the easiest way to fix this is to replace it with something like this

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/VCqhZiCnz/your-result-here?orgId=1&from=now-24h&to=now&panelId=4" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I haven't found a way to set this properly fix/set this in the UI so I'm welcome to suggestions

EDIT : You may need to add a `refresh` parameter depending on the way your grafana dashboard is setup

Comment: Found a way to fix/set what in the UI exactly? (If I remember I'll try to respond with some of my findings as well)